# Checkout form not being saved

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develop an e-commerce site with Django. So I'm at this point where, users can add items to their cart, proceed to checkout but for some reason, my checkout form is not being saved. I made sure that I have registered my models, and ran migrations, but everytime I fill out my form and go to check in my admin panel, it says: 0 user addresses.

Also after clicking the submit button, it's not getting redirected to checkout, rather it's being redirected to:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=a8vjroAuxAcGFjQmwZ6CdBL5DhYui0vKVnANaoi8lxY33uqjmLXaT90tze6Anyun&address=123+Main+Street%2C+234+Irvine&address2=234+Irvine&state=MA&country=United+States&zipcode=55525&phone=8773140742&billing=on`

What is the problem?

My views.py:

```
@login_required
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            address_form = UserAddressForm(request.POST)
            if address_form.is_valid():
                new_address = address_form.save(commit= False)
                new_address.user = request.user
                new_address.save()
                return redirect(reverse("checkout"))
    else:
        address_form = UserAddressForm()
    context = {"address_form": address_form}
    template = "orders/checkout.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

My checkout.html:

```
<form method="POST" action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">   
        {{ address_form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="Place Order"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

My urls.py:

```
from orders import views as orders_views
path('checkout/', orders_views.checkout, name='checkout'),
```

Comment: Why haven't you added the ```action``` in the form

Comment: This question appears in a sequence of 11 questions from the same author on the same, or nearly the same topic. Many of these are copy-paste duplicate of each other, and will serve to waste the time of helpful readers who have not checked how many times the question has been re-asked.